# How to convert correlated sub query to pyspark code

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert correlated subquery in to pyspark code and i am getting below error.

> Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation:

Sample sql query:

```sql
select(few columns)
from table0 spw1 
JOIN table1 spw2
       ON ( spw2.date_key=(SELECT MAX(date_key)
                            FROM table2 spw3
                            WHERE spw3.name =spw1.name
                            AND spw3.id = spw1.id
                            AND spw3.v_key=spw1.v_key
                            AND spw3.start_date < spw1.prev_start_date)
```